# Android Spinner not displaying array, but showing places

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I've been trying to figure out how to make my spinner work for days straight now, and can't find anything to help me. My spinner doesn't show the values. The spinner opens up, and the spaces for each value is there, but they're all blank. I have tried using an `ArrayList<String>`, and also a `String[]` array, neither of which made a difference, but do I need to use one over the other? I have tried many different types of ArrayAdapters, but none of them have worked. The one in my code below is the one that works the closest, (as described above), and the other 3 are suggestions I saw online. I think my main problem is in my array adapter, but I'm not certain.

Here is my java class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);

    engineSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.rockets);
    engineNameList = StagesData.getEngineNameList();
    engStrList = engineNameList.toArray(new String[engineNameList.size()]);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(InfoActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, engStrList);
    // adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.array_engines);
    // adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(InfoActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, R.id.rockets, engStrList);
    // adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(InfoActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.engines);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    engineSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    engineSpinner.setSelection(0);
```

Here is my xml spinner setup

```
<TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/rocket"
            android:padding="3dp"/>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/rockets"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:entries="@array/engines"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorblack"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </TableRow>
```

And finally, this is my string-array file I wanted to pull from (Do I put my string-array in it's own file in the values folder, or does it go inside the string file, I've seen both and don't know which, Thanks)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<resources>
      <string-array name="engines">
            <item>Ant</item>
            <item>Dart</item>
            <item>Dawn</item>
            <item>Flea</item>
            <item>Hammer</item>
            <item>Kickback</item>
            <item>MainSail</item>
            <item>Mammoth</item>
            <item>Nerv</item>
            <item>Poodle</item>
            <item>Puff</item>
            <item>R.A.P.I.E.R</item>
            <item>Reliant</item>
            <item>Rhino</item>
            <item>Skipper</item>
            <item>Spark</item>
            <item>Spider</item>
            <item>Swivel</item>
            <item>Terrier</item>
            <item>Thud</item>
            <item>Thumper</item>
            <item>Twin Boar</item>
            <item>Twitch</item>
            <item>Vector</item>
      </string-array>
</resources>
```

So to recap my questions, do I need to use `ArrayList<String>` or `String[]`, how do I set up my ArrayAdapter, and where do I need to put my string-array?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your issues was solved?

Comment: Yes it was. Sorry I didn't respond right away. Thank you so much. I'm new to android programming and I think my first app is a bit too complicated to be doing as my first one, but it's coming along. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreate your sample and works fine for me changing

```
engStrList = engineNameList.toArray(new String[engineNameList.size()]); 
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(InfoActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, engStrList);
```

to

```
engStrList = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(InfoActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, engStrList);
```

So my guess is that you should check what `StagesData.getEngineNameList()` is returning.

---

Also if you what to use your string array this is the right way

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.engines));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I had been trying to get that working for days. I tried your last suggestion, it worked perfectly. I guess my .getEngineNameList() wasn't returning the string array list as I was hoping.